# Windowed IDENTITY column definition?

Tags: sql-server, schema, identity

Is it possible to create a windowed identity column that automatically initializes and increments in SQL Server 2017 or later?

I would like the conceptual functionality of `SelectedSubsetId` below.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SelectedSubset
(
    ItemSetId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.ItemSet(ItemSetId),
    SelectedSubsetId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemSetId),
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ItemSetId, SelectedSubsetId )
)
```

Where `SelectedSubsetId` would start at 1 and increment by 1 for each `ItemSetId` entered.  Another table would would foreign key this primary key and add the item ids of the set

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SubsetItems
(
    ItemSetId INT NOT NULL,
    SelectedSubsetId INT NOT NULL,
    ItemId INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ItemSetId, SelectedSubsetId) REFERENCES dbo.SelectedSubset(ItemSetId, SelectedSubsetId),
    FOREIGN KEY (ItemSetId, ItemId) REFERENCES dbo.ItemSetItems(ItemSetId, ItemId),
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ItemSetId, SelectedSubsetId, ItemId)
)
```

In this concept `SelectedSubsetId` is only defined by its `ItemId`s. It has no attributes of its own that warrant creating a table to hold additional information.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I have created a suggestion ([36768604](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/36768604-implement-a-windowed-identity-column-definition)) on Microsoft's site.

Comment: I marked this as duplicate of similar questions. There are answers/workarounds there (one by Aaron Bertrand, using a trigger). If you feel your question is different, please explain and we could reopen it.

Comment: Neither options (trigger, new dynamically creatde sequence per ItemSet) looks pretty but there you go, you have options.